# GSM MODEM : AT COMMAND to know my operator

Tags: at-command

Can any one please let me know, is there any AT command by which I can detect the current operator name?

I have used AT+COPS?
It returned me the numeric code for the operator:  0,2,40410

Then I used the command AT+WOPN = 0,40410 which returns the alphanumeric value for the operator

but that only gives Airtel operator's name, and for other operators it gives an error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 13):

You should use `AT+COPS=<mode>,[<format>,<oper>[,<AcT>]]` command as [was pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13643392/483573), but `<mode>` value need to be `3` to not to override your existing `<mode>` value:

```
<mode>: integer type
3   set only <format> (for read command +COPS?), do not attempt
    registration/deregistration (<oper> and <AcT> fields are ignored);
    this value is not applicable in read command response.
```

And `<format>` need to be 0 or 1

```
<format>: integer type
0   long format alphanumeric <oper>
1   short format alphanumeric <oper>
2   numeric <oper>
```

So your commands are

```
AT+COPS=3,0
AT+COPS?
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the format first.

- `AT+COPS=1,2`

  "2" means numeric format, this will return e.g.40410
- `AT+COPS=1,0`

  "0" means long alphanumeric format, this should return the operator name string.

The first parameter is the `<mode>` - select the value that you need.
For the full documentation of this AT command, see 3GPP TS 27.007 document at http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm

When you have set the mode and format, then send
`AT+COPS?` and you should get the operator name in the format that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try- `AT+QSPN`.

Works for my Quectel modem.

Comment: I am working on Gsm modem and i tired this command but it is giving error. is there a syntax for this & does it works for GSM modem to know the operator...

Comment: Quectel is the manufacturer name. Its a gsm modem too. Did it work?

Comment: For "AT+QSPN" we get syntax error in quectel modem.. It should be "AT+QSPN?"

Comment: In response to other comments, you must read carefully your the manual of your specific modem, as this is a proprietary AT command from Quectel and may not be implemented. For the BG96 the command is exactly as @Cdeez indicated: AT+QSPN